# How to get old value in PropertyGrid TypeConversion?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have a special case of property grid input where I would need to enter a Vector3 under a string format, let's say "0, 5, 1". I built the converter for it as such:

```
public class Vector3Converter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return (sourceType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string[] splitted = ((string)value).Remove(" ").Split(new char[] { ',' });

        return new Vector3(float.Parse(splitted[0]), float.Parse(splitted[1]), float.Parse(splitted[2]));
    }
}
```

Now this works somehow, but for another reason (I won't bother explaining, it's incredibly long, but justified - I couldn't avoid it by changing my initial design), I need to know what value was in the field before setting the new one (which somehow depends on it).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should fix your design so you don't have to do this. Remember that type-converters aren't used exclusively by property-grids, and there's a good chance that a conversion may be required when there is no "old value" to speak of.

This is a bit of a hack, but you can cast the `context` to a [`System.Windows.Forms.GridItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.griditem.aspx), which represents a row on a property-grid,  and then inspect its [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.griditem.value.aspx) property.
Obviously, this isn't going to work when the `ConvertFrom` method is called in a non-property-grid context.

```
public override object ConvertFrom 
     (ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    var gridItem = context as GridItem;

    // If the context is indeed a property-grid item...
    if (gridItem != null)
    {
        var oldVector = (Vector3)gridItem.Value;
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I unfortunately cannot change the design, many constraints just make it impossible (I've tried for months). But this hack works perfectly. Thanks a bunch!